# Some bugs in code using Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a scratch card simulator.

The user should be able to click and drag in order to reveal the text underneath.

I have 2 bugs with this implementaion:

a) Sometimes the scratch card clears itself as soon as the cursor enters the canvas from left or right. It should only clear itself when most of the card has been scratched off. Currently, it only works if the user moves their cursor in from the top border, going downwards.

b) Sometimes the scratch card will not work at all, or the scratching will be offset from the cursor, but only when the browser window is smaller than the document size (e.g., browser window is 300px wide but the body has a min-width of 900px or something and the user had to scroll the card into view).

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var container = document.getElementById('cbox-canvas'),
        arrow = document.getElementById('cbox-arrow'),
        textOne = document.getElementById('cbox-text-1'),
        textTwo = document.getElementById('cbox-text-2'),
        boxOne = document.getElementById('cbox-box-1'),
        boxTwo = document.getElementById('cbox-box-2'),
        cnv = container.getElementsByTagName('canvas'),
        imageCover;

    function createCanvas(parent, width, height) {
        var canvas = {};
        canvas.node = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.context = canvas.node.getContext('2d');
        canvas.node.width = width || 100;
        canvas.node.height = height || 100;
        parent.appendChild(canvas.node);
        return canvas;
    }

    function init(container, width, height, fillColor) {
        var canvas = createCanvas(container, width, height),
            ctx = canvas.context;

        // define a custom fillCircle method
        ctx.fillCircle = function (x, y, radius, fillColor) {
            //this.fillStyle = fillColor;
            this.shadowBlur = 15;
            this.shadowOffsetX = 0;
            this.shadowOffsetY = 0;
            this.shadowColor = fillColor;
            this.beginPath();
            this.moveTo(x, y);

            this.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
            this.fill();
            this.stroke();
        };
        ctx.clearTo = function (fillColor) {

            var imageObj = new Image();

            imageObj.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
            };
            imageObj.src = fillColor;
        };
        ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");

        // bind mouse events
        canvas.node.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var canvasRect = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
                x = e.pageX - canvasRect.left,
                y = e.pageY - canvasRect.top,
                radius = 30,
                calc = 0;

            fillColor = '#ff0000';

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);

            calc += x;
            if (calc > 330 || calc < 6) {
                container.removeChild(cnv[0]);
                arrow.className += " slide-it";
                textOne.className += " reveal-it";
                textTwo.className += " fade-in";
                boxOne.className += " fade-in-two";
                boxTwo.className += " fade-in-one";
            }

        };

        container.onmousemove = function (e) {
            var canvasRect = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
                mouseX = e.pageX || e.clientX,
                mouseY = e.pageY || e.clientY,
                relMouseX = mouseX - canvasRect.left,
                relMouseY = mouseY - canvasRect.top,
                leftLimit = 37,
                topLimit = 37,
                rightLimit = 25,
                bottomLimit = 44,
                x = e.pageX - canvasRect.left,
                y = e.pageY - canvasRect.top,
                radius = 25;

            fillColor = '#ff0000';

            if (relMouseX < leftLimit) {
                relMouseX = leftLimit;
            }
            if (relMouseY < topLimit) {
                relMouseY = topLimit;
            }
            if (relMouseX > width - rightLimit) {
                relMouseX = width - rightLimit;
            }
            if (relMouseY > height - bottomLimit) {
                relMouseY = height - bottomLimit;
            }

            if (!canvas.isDrawing) {
                return;
            }

            ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';
            ctx.fillCircle(x, y, radius, fillColor);

        };
    }

    imageCover = "images/scratch.png";
    init(container, 369, 371, imageCover);
}());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p05kg0vq/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problems

There are several issues here:

1. You are loading the clear image for each time which happens asynchronously and it may not appear in time.
2. The same method, `clearTo()`, also takes a fill-style color, but tries to load it as image
3. You are listening to mouse move events *two* places which is not needed
4. For improvement: You're listening to mouse move events on the canvas. This is not wrong, but it will be more fluid using the window object
5. You're using [pageX/Y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX) to calculate mouse position. These are relative to page not client. [`getBoundingClientRect()` is relative to client](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).
6. Not sure how you intend to calculate coverage
7. There are additional room for refactoring.

### Solutions

1. Load image once globally and use the object as argument instead of the URL.
2. Differentiate between an image and color string. To do this check if argument is a string, if so, set `fillStyle` and use `fillRect()` to clear. If not use `drawImage()`.
3. Remove the event from the container. It's not needed and will conflict with the second listener.
4. Use `window.onmousemove` instead (not required, but a better option in this case as it will move the cursor completely outside canvas - optionally use a parent node that is wider - it's up to you...).
5. Calculate using `clientX` and `clientY` instead and always.
6. Extract the `ImageData` and count pixels with no alpha data (=0). Then divide this count on total number of pixels to get percentage of coverage. This is fast (I'll show how below).
7. Left to OP to improve :)

So, lets modify the structure a bit. This is not optimal, but meant to get you started. Load the image once and globally (or within the parent scope so the object is accessible).

```
// preload image once
var imageCover = "//i.imgur.com/b4m1M1n.png"; // needed cors for demo
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = go;
imageObj.crossOrigin = "";                    // for demo, for getImageData to work
imageObj.src = imageCover;

function go() {

  /* ... inner code not shown ... */

  init(container, 369, 371, imageObj);
};
```

Then rewrite `clearTo()` to accept both image and fill style. Notice this may break browser optimizations as there are two different types involved, but in this case it likely doesn't matter:

```
ctx.clearTo = function(fillColor) {
    if (typeof fillColor === "string") {  // is a string?
      ctx.fillStyle = fillColor;          // set as fill style
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
    }
    else {                                // assumes an image if not string
      ctx.drawImage(fillColor, 0, 0);
    }
};
ctx.clearTo(fillColor || "#ddd");
```

Then move `onmousemove` to `window` object and use `clientX`/`clientY`:

```
window.onmousemove = function(e) {
  var canvasRect = container.getBoundingClientRect(),
    x = e.clientX - canvasRect.left,   // use clientX/Y (pageXY is unofficial)
    y = e.clientY - canvasRect.top,
    /* ... */
```

Within the same code block provide a function calculate real-time coverage of canvas:

```
 // calc converage and clean if < 20%
        if (calcCover(ctx) < 0.2) {
    // end, reveal, etc.
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
    console.log("DONE");
  };
```

The function used here does:

```
function calcCover(ctx) {
  var w = ctx.canvas.width,  // just to cache width/height
      h = ctx.canvas.height,
      // convert Uint8ClampedArray to Uint32Array, no memory loss
      // but faster
      data32 = new Uint32Array(ctx.getImageData(0,0,w,h).data.buffer),
      count = w * h;   // total number of pixels

  // iterate, check for alpha-channel (0xAABBGGRR, little-endian format)
  // for the Uint32Array data.
  for(var i = 0; i < data32.length; i++) if (!(data32[i] & 0xff000000)) count--;

  // convert to a percentage (or rather normalize)
  return count / (w*h);
};
```

Now we are good to go:

**[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/Lf1wps74/)**

Comment: @Kaido if you want the cursor to exit canvas completely you actually don't have much option as listening to the canvas will stop movements when outside the edge but drawing half the cursor. You could use a parent node if bigger than the canvas of course.

Comment: @Kaiido margins won't work in this case. Here's a comparison (they both uses margins) https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/04xn57d5/ You probably meant padding but that will add some potential visual challenges (in case of bg color), as well as forcing to take padding size (left/top) into consideration when calculating rel. mouse pos.

Comment: I meant margins inside the canvas drawing itself (not CSS ones) But actually, a simple mousePos check is simpler, non obtrusive and works just well : https://jsfiddle.net/Lf1wps74/1/

Comment: @Kaiido Sure, but... I wasn't intending to recode or provide coding service for OP. Just to give some hints and solutions to the existing real-world issues that prevents his code from working. You can throttle the code, you can also rescale the image before analyzing the data, you can use a web worker, you can limit the scope/region etc. so you only check one at the time - I am probably old and used to people thinking for themselves .)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code I could only suggest a full rewrite

```js
;(function () {
    "use strict";
    // Generic functions and constants
    const PI2 = Math.PI * 2;
    function applyStyle (ctx, style) { Object.keys(style).forEach(key => ctx[key] = style[key] ) }
    function ease (val, power) { return val < 0 ? 0 : val > 1 ? 1 : Math.pow(val, power) }
    
    // General settings 
    const settings = {
        width : 369,
        height : 371,
        coveragedMin : 0.2, // when to uncover all out of 1
        coverColor : "#ddd",  // colour to show on canvas while main image is loading. (not needed but to keep with you code)
        mouseEvents : "mouseup,mousedown,mousemove".split(","),  // list of mouse events to listen to
        coverImage : loadImage("https://image.ibb.co/f8TNS5/scratch.png"),  // the scratch image
        container : document.getElementById('cbox-canvas'),  // the container
        drawStyle : {  // the draw style of the revealing mouse moves. Note that this adds radius to the context but should not matter
            radius : 20,
            shadowBlur : 15,
            shadowOffsetX : 0,
            shadowOffsetY : 0,
            shadowColor : "black",
            fillStyle : "black",
            globalCompositeOperation : "destination-out",
        },
        startAnim (){    // specific to this scratch reveal animations
            document.getElementById("cbox-arrow").className = "cbox-arrow  slide-it";
            document.getElementById("cbox-text-1").className = "cbox-text-1 reveal-it";
            document.getElementById("cbox-box-1").className = "cbox-box-1 fade-in-two"; 
            document.getElementById("cbox-box-2").className = "cbox-box-2 fade-in-one";
            document.getElementById("cbox-text-2").className = "cbox-text-2 fade-in";
        },
        coverageArray : (() => {const buf = new Uint8Array(64); buf.fill(1); return buf }) (), // array to is used to determine coverage        
    }
    var update = true; // when true update canvas render
    const mouse = { x : 0, y : 0, button : false}; // Mouse state
    function mouseEvent (e) { // handles all mouse events
        const canvasRect = settings.container.getBoundingClientRect();
        mouse.x = e.pageX - canvasRect.left - scrollX;
        mouse.y = e.pageY - canvasRect.top - scrollY;
        if (e.type === "mousedown") { mouse.button = true }
        else if (e.type === "mouseup") { mouse.button = false }
        update = true;  // flags that there needs to be a re render
    }
    function fillCircle (ctx, x, y, style) { // Draws a circle on context ctx, at location x,y using style 
        applyStyle(ctx, style);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, style.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    function setCoverage (array,x,y){  // Clears the coverage array, coordinates x,y are normalised 0-1
        var i = array.length - 1;     // and returns coverage as a value 0 no coverage to 1 full cover
        const size = Math.sqrt(array.length) | 0;
        array[(x * size) | 0 + ((y * size) | 0) * size] = 0;
        var count = 0;
        while(i-- > 0){ count += array[i] };
        return count / array.length;
    }
    function loadImage (url) { // Loads an image and sets a property indicating if its has been rendered
        const image = new Image();
        image.src = url;
        image.rendered = false;
        return image;
    }
    function createCanvas (width, height) { // Creates a canvas of size width and height, set property ctx to the 2D context
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        canvas.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        return canvas;
    }
    (function (settings) { //  Start the app
        const canvas = createCanvas(settings.width, settings.height);
        settings.container.appendChild(canvas);
        const ctx = canvas.ctx;
        settings.mouseEvents.forEach(eventName => addEventListener(eventName, mouseEvent)); // start the mouse
        var reveal = false;  // when true reveal the prize (yep suckers) ???
        var fade = 1;   // fades out the canvas 
        ctx.fillStyle = settings.coverColor;  // cover while waiting for image to load
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // image will not yet have loaded so cover image
        (function mainLoop () {  // main animation loop will play unt ill canvas faded out
            if (settings.coverImage.complete && !settings.coverImage.rendered) { // wait till image has loaded
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                ctx.drawImage(settings.coverImage, 0, 0, settings.width, settings.height);
                settings.coverImage.rendered = true;
                const swipeEl = document.getElementById("swipe-area");
                swipeEl.className = "swipe-area loaded";
                swipeEl.title = "Use your mouse to reveal your PRIZE :P";
            }
            if (update) {  // only if needed render canvas
                if (settings.coverImage.rendered) {
                    mouse.button && fillCircle(ctx, mouse.x, mouse.y, settings.drawStyle);
                    setCoverage(settings.coverageArray, mouse.x /  settings.width, mouse.y / settings.height) < settings.coveragedMin && (reveal = true);
                    update = false;
                }
                if (reveal) {
                    fade -= 0.05;
                    canvas.style.opacity = ease(fade,2);
                    update = true; // need continuous update for animation
                }
            }
            if (reveal && fade <= 0) { // scratching all done remove canvas, mouse events and start any animations. Do not call requestAnimationFrame as all done. 
                const swipeEl = document.getElementById("swipe-area");
                swipeEl.style.cursor = "pointer";
                swipeEl.title = "Click here to collect your $$$$";
                settings.container.removeChild(canvas);
                settings.mouseEvents.forEach(eventName => removeEventListener(eventName, mouseEvent));
                settings.startAnim();
                // All done. All objects should now have no references (important to remove mouse and requestAnimation frame) and any other functions
                // that can hold a closure 
            } else {              
                requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
            }
        } () );
    } (settings) );
} () );
```

```css
/*SWIPE*/

.swipe-area {
  position: absolute;
  width: 369px;
  height: 371px;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 15;
  background-size: 100%;
}
.preload {
  cursor : wait;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/f8TNS5/scratch.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
 }
.loaded {
  cursor : url('data:image/png;base64,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') 9 20, pointer;

  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/j4j7uk/sc_bg.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;  
}
.anim-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 360px;
  height: 366px;
  right: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: -1;
  background-size: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cbox-arrow {
  position: absolute;
  left: 56px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 260px;
  height: 264px;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/fXKwn5/arrow.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-animation: 10s slide;
}

.cbox-text-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 72px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 230px;
  height: 65px;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/d6YYZk/test1.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

.cbox-text-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 72px;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 230px;
  height: 65px;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/bCaQfQ/test2.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cbox-box-1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 55px;
  top: 167px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 257px;
  height: 65px;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/fG7hS5/box1.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}

.cbox-box-2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 135px;
  top: 124px;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 99px;
  height: 127px;
  background: url('https://image.ibb.co/dOSSuk/box2.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.hidden {  display: none;}
/* unknowns */

.newslisting, #sidebar1Bottom { background: #ffffff !important; }
.tmx header { height: 269px;}

/*Animations, you can add agent prescripts, though we should never have to do that */
.fade-in { animation: 1.5s 2.5s fade;}
.fade-in-one { animation: 2.5s 5s fade;}
.fade-in-two { animation: 2.5s 7.5s fade-alt forwards;}
.fade-in-three { animation: 5s 15s fade;}
.reveal-it { animation: 2.5s reveal forwards;}
.slide-it { animation: 5s slide-in forwards;}
@keyframes fade-alt {0% { opacity: 0; } 10% {opacity : 1;} 100% {  opacity: 1;} }
@keyframes fade { 0% { opacity: 0; } 10% {opacity: 1;} 90% {opacity: 1;} 100% {opacity: 0;} }
@keyframes reveal {0% {  opacity: 1;} 80% { opacity: 1;} 100% { opacity: 0;} }
@keyframes slide-in {0% { top: 5px; }  80% { top: 5px; } 100% { top: -150px;} }
```

```html
<div class="swipe-area preload" id="swipe-area" title="Just a moment as we asses your gullibility!">
  <div id="cbox-canvas">
    <div class="anim-container">
      <div id="cbox-arrow" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="cbox-text-1" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="cbox-box-1" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="cbox-box-2" class="hidden"></div>
      <div id="cbox-text-2" class="hidden"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```